# How do I debug specific pages with Eclipse PDT and remote ZendDebug

Tags: php, remote-debugging, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I've recently managed to get Zend Debugger up and rolling through a remote connection for our development servers. Our application is divided mainly into two different servers, each are distinct projects in eclipse.

The problem I have is when debugging, I need to be able to raise a breakpoint in eclipse from a specific url. Assuming that my debugger is correctly installed and that the code on the server matches the code on my local machine, is it possible, using my preferred web browser, to invoke the correct file in the eclipse debugger (by adding parameters to the url or something along the lines) ? If so, how do I accomplish this ?

(Using Eclipse Helios)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this, the way I had initially asked, is impossible. I thought it mght work with something similar to Xdebug's XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY parameters, but looking back that isn't the case.

However, by digging deeper in the Eclipse configuration, you can launch the browser of your choice instead of the built-in Eclipse debugger, regardless your debugger plugin.

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser